# How to set MediaElement source

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, mediaelement, playlist

I'm making a music player in C# WPF. Files are added to a ListBox which works as the playlist for the MediaElement. In order to only show the filename without path and extension in the ListBox, I made a `Song` class which has properties for path and title.

What I can't figure out is how to set the MediaElements source to the path property of the `Song` object, so that I can just click an item in the ListBox and it would start playing.

Here's the code I use for adding files to the listbox:

```
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string file in ofd.FileNames)
            {
                Song songs = new Song(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), file);
                listBox.Items.Add(songs);                                                                           
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the path in your `Song` class as well as just the filename. Then when you select the item you have the path immediately available to you. You can have as many properties on the `Song` class as you like. Just use the [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) property to control what gets displayed and the [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx) property to control what aspect of the item you need to return to the code. In this case you could use the filename as the `DisplayMemberPath` and the path as the `SelectedValuePath`.

You don't really need to store just the filename as you can pass the path through a converter to extract the filename for display. Obviously there would be a processing overhead for this and the extra memory storing the filename would take isn't really an issue, but I thought it was worth a mention.